# Coredata NSFetchedResultsController predicate on One-To-Many relationship (outside in)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a the following setup in my coredata xcdatamodel:

[image]

Basically there are a set of Articles (TMArticle) in the website which will be categorised into Sections (TMSection) and Journals (TMJournal). The app navigation would have to display all sections first and then **navigate to display only a list of journals which are contained in all articles belonging to the selected section**. I am not quite sure as to how I can accomplish this without an inverse relationship. Ideally speaking in this setup there is no need for inverse relationship (from section and journal back to Articles), but how can I write a predicate which does exactly what I seek for?

I get list of all articles using the following FRC:

```
@synthesize articlesFRC = articlesFRC_;
-(NSFetchedResultsController*)articlesFRC {
    if (nil==articlesFRC_) {
        NSFetchRequest *articlesFR = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[TMArticle entityName]];
        NSSortDescriptor *articleSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"nid"
                                                                    ascending:NO];
        [articlesFR setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:articleSD]];
        articlesFRC_ = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:articlesFR
                                                           managedObjectContext:[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore] managedObjectContextForCurrentThread]
                                                             sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                      cacheName:nil];
        [articlesFRC_ setDelegate:self];
        [articlesFRC_ performFetch:NULL];
    }
    return articlesFRC_;
}
```

However, I am stuck at creation of FRC for fetching only those journals which belong to articles for which the user has already selected a section, placeholder predicate for my FRC:

```
@synthesize journalsFRC = journalsFRC_;
-(NSFetchedResultsController*)journalsFRC {
    if (nil==journalsFRC_ && nil!=self.selectedSectionManagedObjectID) {
        NSFetchRequest *journalFR = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[TMJournal entityName]];
        NSSortDescriptor *journalSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"weight"
                                                                    ascending:YES];
        [journalFR setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:journalSD]];
        [journalFR setPredicate:<#(NSPredicate * _Nullable)#>];
        journalsFRC_ = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:journalFR
                                                           managedObjectContext:[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore] managedObjectContextForCurrentThread]
                                                             sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                      cacheName:nil];
        [journalsFRC_ setDelegate:self];
        [journalsFRC_ performFetch:NULL];
    }
    return journalsFRC_;
}
```

I also would want to ensure that any changes to selection of section or an update in list of articles through webservice call should automatically update the list of Journals which satisfy the condition, I am not quite sure as to how I can accommodate the same in the predicate above.

**Additional Info**:

Forgot to mention earlier that **taxonomyID** is the primary key for both Sections (TMSection) and Journals (TMJournal), while **nid** is the primary key for articles (TMArticle).

A sample webservice response for each:

Article list:

```
[
    {
        "nid": "3",
        "listing_post_date": "Tuesday, August 15, 2017 - 19:49",
        "listing_updated_date": "Tuesday, August 15, 2017 - 19:49",
        "title": "ACL Tear",
        "field_journal": [
            {
                "tid": "6"
            },
            {
                "tid": "7"
            }
        ],
        "field_section": [
            {
                "tid": "2"
            },
            {
                "tid": "8"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "nid": "1",
        "listing_post_date": "Saturday, March 25, 2017 - 14:23",
        "listing_updated_date": "Sunday, April 9, 2017 - 10:51",
        "title": "Reverse Total Shoulder arthroplasty",
        "field_journal": [
            {
                "tid": "3"
            },
            {
                "tid": "4"
            }
        ],
        "field_section": [
            {
                "tid": "2"
            },
            {
                "tid": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Section list:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sports",
        "field_section_image": [],
        "tid": "2",
        "weight": "0",
        "field_section_color": {
            "rgb": "#bbf1f3"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Hand",
        "field_section_image": [],
        "tid": "5",
        "weight": "1",
        "field_section_color": {
            "rgb": "#96c394"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Knee",
        "field_section_image": [],
        "tid": "8",
        "weight": "2",
        "field_section_color": {
            "rgb": "#f29d9d"
        }
    }
]
```

Journal list:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Bone &amp; Joint Research",
        "tid": "3",
        "weight": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sports Journal",
        "tid": "7",
        "weight": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sports Medicine",
        "tid": "4",
        "weight": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "The Knee Journal",
        "tid": "6",
        "weight": "0"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should almost always specify inverses for every relationship; there are very few situations where you are better off without.

Looking at your data, it seems that a given section can be related to many articles, so add a to-many relationship from `TMSection` to `TMArticle`.

The data only has journals being related to one article; if that is universally true then you can add a to-one relationship from `TMJournal` to `TMArticle`.

Then use the following predicate to fetch `TMJournals`:

```
[journalFR setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY article.sections == %@", self.selectedSectionManagedObjectID];
```

Sadly the FRC will only observe changes to the `Journal` objects, so you will need to specifically handle changes to either the Articles or the selection `Section`.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, however, a journal can have one-to-many relationship with articles too, the data is sample data in my case. So, if I establish a many-to-many relationship between Article-Section and Article-Journal how will the predicate change? Also, my knowledge in Drupal is limited, so I cannot maintain many-to-many relationship mapping in server. With this data, is there a way I can establish many-to-many relationship automatically in coredata?

Comment: I just made the changes in relationship of xcdatamodel with proper inverse relationship as per your suggestion, turns out that the inverse relationship is automatically managed and maintained by coredata once a journal is added into article and the same with section too. Thanks for the direction! I just need to figure out the predicate in case of many-to-many relationship between journal and articles.

Comment: I think you will need to use a nested subquery - can't remember the exact syntax, and not by my Mac to check.  Try `"SUBQUERY(articles,$A,SUBQUERY($A.sections,$S,$S == %@).@count > 0).@count > 0", selectedSectionManagedObjectID`.